# LINQ to SQL Class Diagrams

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows, linq

Could someone show me how to change the Relationship Diagram below into class diagrams please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio create a new DataContext.dbml file and then either drag and drop the relevant tables from your data connection or use the provided tools to generate the wanted classes.